# Generating an SSH key from Java

Tags: java, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I have a Java program that is trying to run shell commands on a Linux machine, with the specific command being to generate an SSH key. These keys need to have no password, so I'm trying to run it with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f my_key_name -P ""`. I know this command works, because I can run it on the command line just fine. But when I try to run it with the below code, it says `passphrase is too short (minimum five characters)`.

I could change the below code to be: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f my_key_name -P "foobar"` and that does work properly with Java, but again I don't want a password.

```
RunCommandDto runCommandDto = new RunCommandDto();
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec('ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f my_key_name -P ""');

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

String output = "";

while ((String sInOut = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    output += sInOut + "\n";
}

while ((String sErr = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
     output += sErr + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Try passing it as a command array (eg `new String[] {"ssh-keygen", "-t", "rsa", "-b", "4096", "-f", "my_key_name", "-P", ""}`. IIRC interpretation of `""` in your command line is a shell thing, and the shell is not involved here; in the command array you would just pass an empty string.

Comment: Not necessarily related to this question, but in general you should prefer using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run a subprocess rather than `Runtime::exec`. `ProcessBuilder` exposes many more options and is generally easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried creating it by running the command in which I am passing the file that contains the command. And I was able to create the file.
Here is my test:

```
   @Test
   public void test() throws IOException {
      String output = "";
      String sInOut;
      String sErr;
      //      RunCommandDto runCommandDto = new RunCommandDto();

      String[] cmd = { "sh", "~/ssh_key_gen.sh"};

      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process proc = rt.exec( cmd );

      BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( proc.getInputStream() ) );
      BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( proc.getErrorStream() ) );
      while ( (sInOut = stdInput.readLine()) != null ) {
         output += sInOut + "\n";
      }

      while ( (sErr = stdError.readLine()) != null ) {
         output += sErr + "\n";
      }

      System.out.println("if failed: " + output);
   }
```

And my file that contains the command looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f /tmp/sshkey -q -N ""
```

Please note: you can may either get the absolute path for your file 'ssh_key_gen.sh' or you can get relative path to it.